# icons on a listview , jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, icons

I have a listview and i want to add some icons. I want the final result to look like this here:

[Stanford Mobile Webpage](http://m.stanford.edu)

As you can see the icons look really nice(same size as the text). Now i am trying to do the same with my project. However i get this result:

[image]

As you can see the icon looks really small... I am viewing the page source of the Stanford site and what they do is :

```
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="news/"><img src="img/icon/news.png" alt="News" class="ui-li-icon">News</a></li>
    </ul>
```

that means they add the `class="ui-li-icon"` attribute in the list. But this results in a really small icon..(i tried with 48x48 , 32x32 ...)

How can i fix this? Any ideas?

### EDIT

---

Since i am trying to replicate the behavior of the aforementioned site , heres the CSS from the stanford page. Maybe someone can see where exactly they give this behavior.

```
/* Widen and center h1 text between "Back" and "Home" buttons */
.ui-title {
    width:50%;
    margin-left:26% !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    padding: 5px 0 !important;
}
/* Align Home button left */
.ui-header .ui-btn-right {
    left:10px;
    right:inherit;
}
/* Capitalize header h1 */
.ui-header h1 {
    text-transform:capitalize;  
}
/* Full Site/About icon spacing */
.ui-btn-inner {
    padding-left:40px;  
}
/* Nested list width fix http://bit.ly/fJGPsg */
.ui-li .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit {
    padding-top:0.7em;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-bottom:0.7em;
}
/* Remove background seal */
.ui-content {
    background:none;
}
/* Make time aside smaller to allow for longer titles */
.ui-li-aside {
    width:20% !important;
}
/* add space after list dividers */
ul.copy-divider {
    margin:20px -15px 0 -15px !important;
}
/* Home page banner */
h2#banner {
    background:transparent url(../img/banner/banner.jpg) no-repeat left 10px;
    width:320px;
    height:284px;
    margin:-10px auto -150px auto;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
/* Home page banner landscape */
.landscape h2#banner {
    background:transparent url(../img/banner/banner-landscape.jpg) no-repeat left 10px;
    width:480px;
    height:290px;
    margin:-10px auto -175px auto;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
/* Remove reduntant extra top padding - don't put h2's in front of ul.listview */
h2 {
    margin:0;
    font-size:20px;
}
/* Home page icons */
.ui-li-icon {
    top:0.4em !important;
}
/* Make room for icons */
.ui-li-has-icon .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit, .ui-li-static.ui-li-has-icon {
    padding-left:47px;
}
/* Add space after intro paragraphs */
p.intro {
    margin-bottom:30px !important;
}
/* Search box top margin */
.ui-listview-filter {
    margin-top:20px;
}
/* Remove bold from grid */
.ui-grid-b {
    font-weight:normal; 
}
/* About */
#about-stanford {
    background:url(../img/logos/about-stanford.png) no-repeat left top;
    text-indent:-5000px;
    width:254px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
/* Dynamic pages */

/* News */
/* Thumbnails */
.ui-li-thumb {
    top:21px;
}
/* Don't append headline */
#news h3 {
    white-space:normal;
}
/* Events */
/* Capitalize first letter in Events pages */
#event h1 {
    text-transform:capitalize;  
}
/* Don't append headline in Events list page paragraphs */
#event h3, #featured h3, #today h3 {
    white-space:normal;
    padding-bottom:1px; /* Make room for links bottom-border */
}
/* Format Events thumbnails to match News thumbs size for consistencey */
#event .ui-li-thumb, #featured .ui-li-thumb, #today .ui-li-thumb {
    top:auto;
    max-height:80px;
}
/* e theme */
.ui-btn-up-e { /* Lighter gradient: light to dark */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(rgba(157,149,115,.5)), to(rgba(157,149,115,.7)));
    border:#000 !important;
}
.ui-btn-hover-e { /* Darker gradient: light to dark */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(rgba(196,191,169,.7)), to(rgba(196,191,169,1)));
    border:red;
}
ui-btn-down-e {
    background:green;
    border:green;
}
```

Comment: you can override the class. `.ui-listview .ui-li-icon { max-height: 48px !important; max-width: 48px !important; }`

Comment: yes it looks bigger now , but terribly mispositioned. almost between 2 elements of the list

Comment: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/#list-thumb check this. you dont need to add any class, just add an image as first child.

Comment: if i understand well now you are telling me to add a thumbnail? This makes each element of the list significally bigger that i dont like. i want it to look like a normal listview with small cells. Not the big ones that are created if you use thumbnails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your icon image size 40x40 px.

Find jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css that you are using, replace this old css with new one.

## OLD CSS

```
.ui-listview .ui-li-icon { 
    max-height: 16px; 
    max-width: 16px; 
    left: 10px; 
    top: .9em; 
}
```

## NEW CSS

```
.ui-listview .ui-li-icon {
    max-height: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    left: 10px;
    top: .9em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I used the above suggestion with a smaller graphic (14pxx11px) but the "left" and "top" CSS settings helped position it. I used the `style='left:10px; top=2em;'` in the <img> tag since due to the design I was using I couldn't adjust an CSS files or <style> section.

Answer (score 0):

@yeyene gave an excellent answer when you know the proportions of the icon beforehand. In some cases you know only the height if the icon. Try re-defining the `.ui-listview .ui-li-icon` classes:

```
.ui-listview .ui-li-icon {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  position: static !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

The `max-height` and `max-width` attributes give image its original size defined by `height` and `width` attributes. The other three attributes make image aligned with the text row.

To get rid of the default left padding you can add an extra class to your links:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="news/" class="custom-listlink"><img src="img/icon/news.png" alt="News" class="ui-li-icon">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="events/" class="custom-listlink"><img src="img/icon/events.png" alt="Events" class="ui-li-icon">Events</a></li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
.custom-listlink {
  padding-left: 1em !important;
}
```